# Handshake problems with CloudMQTT - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, websocket, mqtt, handshake

I'm trying to develop a Web-App using Angular + Ionic and I cannot establish an handshake with the server of my instance in CloudMQTT. The error given is

> Error during Websocket handshake: net::: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

How can I solve this problem?

This is my connection code in the app-module.ts:

```
export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = {
  hostname: 'tailor.cloudmqtt.com',
  port: 34804,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
};
```

This is the code in the component:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public sensorName: string;
  public values: any[];

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute, private mqttService: MqttService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

     this.sensorName = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('sensorName');

     console.log('I am trying to connect!');

     this.subscription = this.mqttService.observe('sensors/' + this.sensorName).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
        let value: any;
        value = message.payload.toString();
        console.log(value);
        let parsedValue: any;
        if ( this.sensorName === 'Humidity' || 'Temperature' ) {
           parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);
        } else {
          parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
        }
        this.values.push(parsedValue);
        });

    }

}
```